# How to get the return type of a contract

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I was reviewing the code from https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week05/src/Week05/NFT.hs and I don't understand why this section does not cause a compile error.

```
utxos <- utxosAt $ npAddress np
    case Map.keys utxos of
        []       -> Contract.logError @String "no utxo found"
        oref : _ -> do
```

```
utxosAt :: forall w s e. AsContractError e => Address -> Contract w s e (Map TxOutRef ChainIndexTxOut)
```

```
keys :: Map k v -> [k]
```

My expectation is that the variable utxos has type Contract w s e (Map TxOutRef ChainIndexTxOut). This should cause an error on `Map.keys utxos`, but it doesn't.

Edit:
My code:

```
getNFT :: Wallet -> Value
        getNFT w = do
            utxos <- utxosAt $ mockWalletAddress w
            case getValue utxos of
                Just v -> v
                Nothing -> Ada.lovelaceValueOf 1000000
```

The type of getValue is `getValue :: Map.Map TxOutRef ChainIndexTxOut -> Maybe Value`

The errors I am getting are:

```
 error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Value’
                  with actual type ‘Contract w0 s0 e0 b0’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: utxos <- utxosAt $ mockWalletAddress w
      In the expression:
        do utxos <- utxosAt $ mockWalletAddress w
           case getValue utxos of
             Just v -> v
             Nothing -> lovelaceValueOf 1000000
      In an equation for ‘getNFT’:
          getNFT w
            = do utxos <- utxosAt $ mockWalletAddress w
                 case getValue utxos of
                   Just v -> v
                   Nothing -> lovelaceValueOf 1000000
    |
179 |             utxos <- utxosAt $ mockWalletAddress w
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation Error, Line 181, Column 27 (jump)
 error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Contract w0 s0 e0 b0’
                  with actual type ‘Value’
    • In the expression: v
      In a case alternative: Just v -> v
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        case getValue utxos of
          Just v -> v
          Nothing -> lovelaceValueOf 1000000
    |
181 |                 Just v -> v
    |                           ^
Compilation Error, Line 182, Column 28 (jump)
 error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Contract w0 s0 e0 b0’
                  with actual type ‘Value’
    • In the expression: lovelaceValueOf 1000000
      In a case alternative: Nothing -> lovelaceValueOf 1000000
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        case getValue utxos of
          Just v -> v
          Nothing -> lovelaceValueOf 1000000
    |
182 |                 Nothing -> Ada.lovelaceValueOf 1000000
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire computation is in the `Contract` monad and we use the `do` notation. Thus when we write `utxos <- utxosAt $ npAddress np`, the type of `utxos` is `Map TxOutRef ChainIndexTxOut`, so everything typechecks.

A simpler example:

```
import Text.Read
plusOne :: String -> Maybe Integer
plusOne s = do
 x <- readMaybe s :: Maybe Integer
 return $ x + 1
```

The type of `readMaybe` is (here) `String -> Maybe Integer`, but since we are after `do`, `x` is of type `Integer`, not `Maybe Integer`. So `plusOne "3"` is `Just 4`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I verified your response, read up on do notation and decided to try using this concept in my own project. I'm not getting the results I expected and edited my original post in hopes you could take a look for me.

Comment: The problem is that `getNFT :: Wallet -> Value` and Value is not a Monad, so you can't use the do notation there. Also,`utxosAt` is a computation in the `Contract` monad, so maybe you want to change to `getNFT :: Wallet -> Contract w s e Value`, where you might have concrete types for the variables w, s, e. Then you should also have `return v` on one case branch, and accordingly `return` on the other branch.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place, but I'll explain a bit more: if you write a function `f :: String -> Integer` you can't use `do` - it's just for instances of the `Monad` class. Also, you can't mix the monads: in a function `g :: a -> Maybe b` you can use `do` but you can't write `x <- h y` where `h :: y -> m x` and `m` is another monad than `Maybe` - note that I use `y` both for a type and a value of that type, to simplify matters.

Comment: through your advice I was able to fix my functions and gain a better understanding of how Monads work. Having my function `getNFT` return a `Contract` monad causes another problem for me because I need to pass the Value in `Contract w s e Value` into `mustPayToPubKey :: forall i o. PaymentPubKeyHash -> Value -> TxConstraints i o`

Comment: If you share your whole code with me, I'll try to help. I would guess you must replace a `let v = getNFT ...` with `v <- getNFT ...`, as `mint` is in the `Contract` monad already.

Comment: https://github.com/DappDeveloper1/Royalty/blob/main/Royalty.hs ---- you'll find that it currently doesn't compile because getNFT returns a Contract and the nft variable in SellParams expects a Value. If I change SellParams to expect a Contract Value, it creates another problem because Contract does not support Show, Generic, FromJSON, and ToJSON

Comment: You shouldn't have  a Contract in SellParams, it's not how it's done. And you also can't have `nft = getNFT ...` there because you expect a Value and get a Contract ... Value. You also can't say `ǹft <- getNFT ...` before the `callEndpoint` because you are in the EmulatorTrace monad and this computation is in the Contract monad. It seems to me you should make `getNFT`  a part of sell - this is where it conceptually belongs.